# Python delete a value from dictionary and not the key

Tags: python

Is it possible to delete a value from  a dictionary and not the key? For instance, 
I have the following code in which the user selects the key corresponding to the element that he wants to delete it , but I want do delete only the value and not the key ( the value is a list):

```
if (selection == 2):
    elem = int(input("Please select the KEY that you want to be deleted: "))
    if dictionar.has_key(elem):
        #dictionar.pop(elem)
        del dictionar[elem]
    else:
        print("the KEY is not present ")
```

Comment: What if you do `dictionar[elem] = None`

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated. Use `elem in dictionar`.

Comment: just set the value equal to the None constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Dictionaries consist of key/value pairs. You cannot have a key without a value. The best you can do is set that key's value to `None` or some other sentinel value, or use a different data structure that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are data structures with `{key:value}` pairs.

To work with values, you can do replace the value with some other value or `None` like below:

```
dic = {}
e = int(input("KEY to be deleted/replaced: "))    

if dic.has_key(e):
    r = int(input("New value to put in or just press ENTER for no new value"))
    if not r:
       r=None
    dic[e]=r
else:
    print("Key Absent")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dictionar = {}
elem = int(input("Please select the KEY that you want to be deleted: "))
if dictionar.has_key(elem)
    dictionar[elem] = ""
else:
    print("The KEY is not present")
```

This code checks if elem is in dictionar then turns the value into a blank string.